# Using .where in Rails Controller Method

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a Statistics page and currently have an `Items Bought` and an `Items Sold` table. The `Items Bought` table is working just fine, however I am having some issues with the `Items Sold` table. There is a boolean in my DB for `SOLD` and I want the count to display for all those items marked as `TRUE`. The current `.where` statements have date statements as well and I'm not sure how to incorporate both of them with it erroring out.

items_controller:

```
def statistics
  @items = Item.all
  @items_day = Item.all.where('created_at >= ? AND created_at <= ?', Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day, Time.zone.now.end_of_day)
  @items_week = Item.all.where('created_at >= ? AND created_at <= ?', Time.zone.now.beginning_of_week, Time.zone.now.end_of_week)
  @items_month = Item.all.where('created_at >= ? AND created_at <= ?', Time.zone.now.beginning_of_month, Time.zone.now.end_of_month)

  @items_sold = Item.all.where(:sold => true)
  @items_sold_day = Item.all.where(:sold => true 'created_at >= ? AND created_at <= ?', Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day, Time.zone.now.end_of_day)
  @items_sold_week = Item.all.where(:sold => true 'created_at >= ? AND created_at <= ?', Time.zone.now.beginning_of_week, Time.zone.now.end_of_week)
  @items_sold_month = Item.all.where(:sold => true 'created_at >= ? AND created_at <= ?', Time.zone.now.beginning_of_month, Time.zone.now.end_of_month)
end
```

statistics.html.erb

```
<h3 id="subtitle">Items Bought</h3>
<table align="center" style="width: 95%" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Total</th>
      <th>Today</th>
      <th>Week</th>
      <th>Month</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><%= number_with_delimiter(@items.count) %></td>
      <td><%= @items_day.count %></td>
      <td><%= @items_week.count %></td>
      <td><%= @items_month.count %></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<h3 id="subtitle">Items Sold</h3>
<table align="center" style="width: 95%" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Total</th>
      <th>Today</th>
      <th>Week</th>
      <th>Month</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><%= number_with_delimiter(@items_sold.count) %></td>
      <td><%= @items_sold_day.count %></td>
      <td><%= @items_sold_week.count %></td>
      <td><%= @items_sold_month.count %></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: First of all you don't need to do `Item.all.where` it should just be `Item.where` and the next thing is that you have used `count` at many places so `@items_sold.count` should do the job for you right?

Comment: Remove the .all  as that makes it an array so you probably want to leave it off  and keep it as an active relation as long as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can chain several `where` statements:

```
Item.where(:sold => true).where('created_at >= ? AND created_at <= ?', Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day, Time.zone.now.end_of_day)
```

Comment: That works great! As soon as I can accept it as the answer, I will. Thanks, again!